# Can school send advertising messages through emergency notification text/automated calls?

Tags: united-states, illinois

I have been receiving calls and texts from my school, using their "emergency" notification service, advertising school events recently.  I provided my number to them in order to receive notifications of school closures or major emergencies, but without consent to use it for marketing purposes.

Is a school (as a governmentally run institution) exempt from the TCPA and other FCC regulations prohibiting marketing robocalls?  Or, is it legal due to the fact that they are not technically selling something (there is no cost to these events)?  Are there any legal hooks to pull on here to prevent them from abusing the emergency notification system for such reasons, or am I limited to solely political ones?